# Gps Location tracking on Google Map

Tags: google-maps, java-me, mobile, gps, location

I want to use Google Map in my j2me application for GPS location.

I want to track the location of other mobile phone from my mobile phone and can able to see in my mobile as Google Map.

Answer (score 1):

[This Forum Nokia](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Google_Maps_API_in_Java_ME) wiki gives an example of how to use Google Maps in Java ME, but beware:

> Usage of this code with the free Google Maps API Key breaks Google's Terms and Conditions (section 10.8).

You'll need some way of getting access to the other handset's location, presumably with the other user's consent.  I guess you'll create another app which sends its location to a server, which your maps app will presumably also be talking to, to find the other user's location.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I think my question is very clear.I just want to use google api for finding location in my mobile.question was very simple but u might not understand it.!!!